# How to handle two different data-main attributes in same page?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am developing a plugin for web applications which uses many external JSs like JStree, bootstrap and jquery. I am also using require to load all of these dynamically.

---

So all that end user would have to do to use this plugin is to include this line in there HTML.

```
<script data-main="http://host.name/pathto/main" src="http://hostname/path.to/require.js"></script>
```

But the problem arises when the app which wants to use this plugin is already using RequireJS for its internal purpose. So now the HTML will have two RequireJS `data-main` attributes like:

```
// The app's RequireJS
<script data-main="app/lib/main" src="app/lib/require.js"></script>
// This is to include plugin I have developed.
<script data-main="http://host.name/pathto/main" src="http://hostname/path.to/require.js"></script>
```

So when there are two different RequireJS instance it always loads the first one's files and other ones are never included. What could be the solution in such case when we are developing addon using RequireJS?

Comment: The additional module should get loaded through the main.app JS.

Comment: you cannot have two data-main attributes on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered you cannot have two `data-main` on the same page. The first `<script>` tag that loads RequireJS will load it and execute it, and RequireJS will take care of loading the code in the corresponding `data-main`. The second `<script>` tag will load and execute RequireJS again but RequireJS will detect that it is *already* loaded and will stop executing right there.

You should have your plugin be loaded through a `require` or `define` call or through the [`deps`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps) configuration option.

If your code needs to add configuration it can call `require.config()` again. RequireJS combines the multiple configurations that are passed to `require.config()` together. Depending on your use-case scenario you may want to use the [`context`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion) option to keep the configuration used by your code completely separate from the main application. If you end up having to use a separate context, it would look something like this:

```
<!-- Load the app. -->
<script data-main="app/lib/main" src="app/lib/require.js"></script>
<!-- Load the plugin. -->
<script>
    var my_require = require.config({
        context: "plugin_context",
        baseUrl:...
    });
    my_require(["main"]);
</script>
```

Comment: ya, that is true but I dont want to touch/mess around the apps code _(main.js)_ to add some _extra_ functionality. Is there a way I can get require's current configuration object and _append_ some of my own _(like path and deps)_?

Comment: So as far as I have got from [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion), the require.config() will always append parameters and it finds a match to existing one it will replace it with newer one, is that correct?

btw, my problem is resolved now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to explain even though you may already have understood. If you call `require.config()` with a `paths` setting mapping `foo` to `"/x/foo"`. And then call `require.config()` with a `paths` mapping `bar` to `"/y/bar"`. The 2 `paths` settings are *combined* in the final config. It is not that the 2nd one *replaces* the 1st one. This is true of complex settings (Object and Array) like `paths` and `shim` (and some others). For settings that are atomic values like `baseUrl` (a string), then you can only replace. When you use `context`, the two configs are kept *completely* separate.